# How can you prevent cursor item helpers from being rerun when the limit changes?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-tracker

Here is a modified leaderboard:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/CgEG3uYBZDceTERXA/Leaderboard

I added a limit to the `players` cursor and display `scorePlusOne` instead of `score`.

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function () {
    return Players.find({}, { sort: { score: -1, name: 1 } , limit: Session.get('limit')});

Template.player.helpers({
  scorePlusOne: function() {
    console.log('scorePlusOne',this.name);
    return this.score + 1;
```

When I increase the limit from 1 to 2, the first player template is not rerendered, but the `scorePlusOne` helper is rerun.

[image]

I don't want any helpers of already-rendered templates to rerun unless they contain reactive data that changes. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Please include all relevant code/data in the question itself, do not outsource it. The day the link dies or points to something else, your question becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache template helper results in `ReactiveVar`s and move the helper code to template autoruns:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4960#issuecomment-132715347

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid helpers to be run when reactive data is updated.

However, one way to overrun this could be to use the `tracker.autorun()` function to wrap a flag to true and allowing your helpers to run or not. It will switch to true as soon your template is re-rendered because of a reactive element.

It would look like this:

```
Template.leaderboard.rendered = function() {
  this.autorun(function(){ 
     flag = true 
  });
};
```

And your helper would look like this:

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function () {
    if (flag===true){
     return Players.find({}, { sort: { score: -1, name: 1 } , limit:            
     Session.get('limit')});
    }
  },
  selectedName: function () {
   if (flag===true){
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selectedPlayer"));
    return player && player.name;
    }
  }
});
```

Each time you make your change, just set your `flag = false` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. So if I change `limit` and set `flag` to false, `selectedName` will skip the next run. But won't it return false/undefined instead of the old value? Seems like I'd have to cache the last value. And what about when I change `limit` and change the contents of Players at the same time? I want the `Players.findOne` to return something different, but wouldn't both invalidations get caught in the same flush?

Comment: The metaphor often used for publications is that it is like a tap you open, water is coming, but you need to wait for it. When you change `limit`, you change your publication. The  flag will only prevent the helpers to run before the DOM is rerendred. Whatever you change, your `autorun` is in the loop. So in the end, it should update your DOM using the right values, and make sure your helpers wait for it.

Comment: The `limit` I speak of is in a minimongo find, not a publication – all the data is on the client. Server data changes could appear at the same time as a limit/flag change, as well as Players being changed in a stub, or if the helper uses other client-only reactive vars, like Session.